# Updating mesh vertex positions per frame (from CPU) in SceneKit

Tags: scenekit, metal

I have custom shader that deforms geometry of SCNNode, however the geometry is not mutated on CPU side which causes issues when trying to interact with the deformed model. A custom blit shader needs to be implemented with an additional MTLBuffer that will copy the deformed vertices back to CPU.

Can anyone provide a code snippet of how to use two MTLBuffers and blit shader to update SCNGeometrySource per frame?

Comment: Is this on iOS or macOS? Are you wrapping your own buffers with a `SCNGeometrySource`, or do you want to read back the contents of a buffer created by SceneKit (I assume the former)?

Comment: Hi! Sorry for late reply. This is for iOS. The first one, where I tried to wrap `SCNGeometrySource` with Metal buffer. However I didn't get it right how to wrap it and use blit shader in order to read updated mesh data back. The purpose of this task is to deform a mesh and then be able to properly interact (using gestures) with it using SceneKit.

Thank you for replying and spending time

Comment: On iOS, where all buffers are in shared memory, you shouldn't need to use a blit encoder to synchronize for reading on the CPU. Of course, you should wait for the deforming shader to finish writing, but after that, you can read the buffer memory directly or `memcpy` it to an array or another buffer.

Comment: Hmm, thank you for enlightening! I would really appreciate if you, may be in your blog or GitHub, publish an example. Of course it is absolutely understandable if you don't want to do that. I think it might be helpful for other developers as well, since it's quite advanced thing. If I figure it out, will publish a link to GitHub here. Thanks a lot!